# Automatic Traffic light sequence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create an automatic light sequence and I have one that will change when clicking a button, however I cannot seem to get it to work automatically. The code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id="light" src="E:\A452\RED traffic light.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list = [
    
    "RED AMBER traffic light.jpg",
    "GREEN traffic light.jpg",
    "AMBER traffic light.jpg",
    "RED traffic light.jpg"

];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Whats your issue ?

Comment: does that image even renders?

Comment: The images won't be loaded since the paths in the array are not complete, as in the `src` of the image tag

Comment: i cant get it to run automaticly without a button